# Как удалить цифры в конце строки python

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Нужно удалить все символы, кроме букв в конце строки. Пример:
rjwqn1124 -> rjwqn
r12jddd289 -> r12jddd

Если цифры между буквами, их нужно оставить. Помогите решить эту проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/[0-9]+$/
```

Поматчит цифры в конце строки

```
/[^a-z]+$/i
```

Отрежет не-буквы в конце